# Why does Chrome fail installing a ClickOnce VSTO for a Word AddIn?

Tags: google-chrome, vsto, clickonce

I have deployed a Word Addin to a specific path. It gets correctly downloaded, but when trying to install it from chrome it fails. (It works on IE, but my client refuses to use that explorer). It has to do with the manifest.dll, but I am not getting further information.

[image: First part of the message]
[image: Second part of the message]

Answer (score 0):

The [DeploymentDownloadException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.deployment.application.deploymentdownloadexception?view=netframework-4.8) indicates that there was an error downloading either the ClickOnce manifests or the deployment's files to the client computer. A `DeploymentDownloadException` can indicate that a number of problems occurred when the user tried to download a ClickOnce application update:

- The client's computer's network connection is down.
- The Web server, FTP server, or file share hosting the update is unavailable.
- One or more of the files in the ClickOnce deployment was not found.

To obtain detailed error information about an exception, consult the ClickOnce error log. For more information, see [Troubleshooting ClickOnce Deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/troubleshooting-clickonce-deployments).

You may want to get a verbose log, see [How to: Specify verbose log files for ClickOnce deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-specify-verbose-log-files-for-clickonce-deployments?view=vs-2019).

---

Native support for ClickOnce applications is only available via Internet Explorer and Edge.

Comment: I would say so, but then, why does it always work with IE?

Comment: Native support for ClickOnce applications is only available via Internet Explorer and Edge.